# Grunt Sass on Windows - permission denied

Tags: ruby, windows, sass, gruntjs

I am trying to run a Sass task with Grunt.

My config is :

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        src: [
          'app/assets/css/sass/*.scss'
        ],
        dest: 'app/assets/css',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

I get an "EISDIR: Is a directory - app/assets/css" error.

I checked many answers and have been trying to resolve that for 2 hours. The directory exists, and I have tried with the full path (C:/...), and using backslashes instead. Same error.

Running sass without grunt works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the trailing slash for `dest` to indicate a directory rather than a file.

Also (missed in first edit), add `expand` to enable dynamic file objects.

**this**

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        src: [
          'app/assets/css/sass/*.scss'
        ],
        dest: 'app/assets/css/',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

**instead of this**

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        src: [
          'app/assets/css/sass/*.scss'
        ],
        dest: 'app/assets/css',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

*edit: added `expand:true` to the original answer and kept the trailing slash on `dest`.*

Comment: Sorry I missed that the first time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, although I had implemented the recommendations made in the approved solution (Matthew), I still faced the same issue.

In fact, some previous instances of Ruby were still running in background. I killed them in the task manager (I am on Windows 7) and the issue disappeared.